# slider/range control in footer issue

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

When adding PhoneGap (Android) to a jQM web app a jQM slider control that should be located in the footer is removed and placed b4 the footer by PhoneGap (?). Adobe PhoneGap Build is used.

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="d" data-id="nav">
<div data-role="navbar" id="mynav">
<ul>
<li><input type="range" name="dayslider" id="dayslider" value="180" min="1" max="365" data-highlight="true" /></li>
<li><input type="button" data-icon="check" data-iconpos="bottom" value="Animate" id="animate" onclick="animY()"></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

What can be the reason? Are there any restrictions (by PhoneGap) on what you can have in a jQM footer?

Answer (score 0):

That should work. I have found JQM, data-position="fixed" does not work well with all devices and changed to absolute CSS positioning. However, you are missing a "/" in the second input. That could be causing an issue.

```
<input type="button" data-icon="check" data-iconpos="bottom" value="Animate" id="animate" onclick="animY()">
```

Should be:

```
<input type="button" data-icon="check" data-iconpos="bottom" value="Animate" id="animate" onclick="animY()"/>
```

Comment: Thank you. I added the missing / but the slider is still outside of the footer.